Botpress API integration with Google Apps Script returns 404 error
I am trying to integrate Botpress with Google Apps Script (GAS), GAS script is a simple web app that retrieves classwork from Google Classroom and sends it to Botpress. However, when I call the GAS URL from Botpress using the Call APi node, I get a 404 error. The configuration is as follows:
GAS Web App:
The GAS web app is deployed with the "Anyone" access setting.
The URL works fine when accessed directly in a browser and returns the expected JSON data.
function doGet(e) {
  const courseId = '733024049691'; // 実世界コンピューティングテストのクラスID
  const optionalArgs = {
    pageSize: 10 // 最大10件のデータを取得
  };

  // クエリパラメータの確認とログ
  if (e != null && e.parameter) {
    const queryParams = e.parameter; // クエリパラメータを取得

    console.log('Received query params:', queryParams);

    // 必要に応じてクエリパラメータを使用
    if (!queryParams.someExpectedParam) {
      console.log('No expected parameter found in the query');
      // ただしクエリが必須でない場合、例外を投げる必要はありません
    }
  }

  try {
    // クラスのリストを取得
    const response = Classroom.Courses.list(optionalArgs);
    const courses = response.courses;

    if (!courses || courses.length === 0) {
      console.log('No courses found.');
      return jsonResponse({
        error: 'No courses found',
        message: 'クラス情報が見つかりませんでした。'
      });
    }

    // 指定されたcourseIdに基づいて課題を取得
    console.log('Fetching course work for courseId: ' + courseId);
    const courseWorkResponse = Classroom.Courses.CourseWork.list(courseId, optionalArgs);
    const courseWorks = courseWorkResponse.courseWork;

    if (!courseWorks || courseWorks.length === 0) {
      console.log('No course works found.');
      return jsonResponse({
        error: 'No course works found',
        message: '指定されたクラスに課題が見つかりませんでした。'
      });
    }

    const botpressDataArray = []; // Botpress に送るデータを配列で保持

    for (const courseWork of courseWorks) {
      const dueDate = courseWork.dueDate;
      const dueTime = courseWork.dueTime;

      if (!dueDate || !dueTime) {
        console.error('Invalid dueDate or dueTime in courseWork:', courseWork);
        continue;  // 次のループに進む
      }

      // UTC時間をJSTに変換
      const utcDate = new Date(Date.UTC(
        dueDate.year,
        dueDate.month - 1, // JavaScriptの月は0ベース
        dueDate.day,
        dueTime.hours,
        dueTime.minutes
      ));

      const jstDate = new Date(utcDate.getTime() + (9 * 60 * 60 * 1000)); // JSTに変換

      const botpressData = {
        "Title": courseWork.title || 'Sample Title', // タイトルがなければデフォルトを使用
        "DueDate": `${jstDate.getMonth() + 1}/${jstDate.getDate()}/${jstDate.getFullYear()}`,
        "DueTime": `${String(jstDate.getHours()).padStart(2, '0')}:${String(jstDate.getMinutes()).padStart(2, '0')}`
      };

      console.log('Botpress Data:', botpressData);
      botpressDataArray.push(botpressData);
    }

    // 成功時のレスポンス
    console.log("Successfully fetched data for Botpress");
    return jsonResponse(botpressDataArray);

  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Failed with error %s', err.message);
    return jsonResponse({
      error: 'Internal Server Error',
      message: 'サーバー内でエラーが発生しました。',
      details: err.message
    });
  }
}

// JSONレスポンスを返すためのユーティリティ関数
function jsonResponse(data) {
  const output = ContentService.createTextOutput();
  output.setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  output.setContent(JSON.stringify(data));
  return output;
}

Error:
I am getting a 404 Not Found error when calling the URL from Botpress.
The URL works in the browser, but Botpress fails to get the data.
What I have tried:
Removed the trailing slash from the URL.
Verified that the web app is set to "Anyone can access".
Tried adjusting the query parameters but nothing works.
Does anyone know why this might be happening or what I can check next? Any help is appreciated!
PS
curl -vvv https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyZsn9eoSKlR86769TYdolbFVCO_CdoYCkGfaILOPrwI4WlpgeoAqyhRzW1NJjnUwpqhg/exec
* Host script.google.com:443 was resolved.
* IPv6: 2404:6800:400a:80e::200e
* IPv4: 142.250.76.142
*   Trying [2404:6800:400a:80e::200e]:443...
* Connected to script.google.com (2404:6800:400a:80e::200e) port 443
* ALPN: curl offers h2,http/1.1
* (304) (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
*  CApath: none
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Unknown (8):
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* (304) (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / AEAD-CHACHA20-POLY1305-SHA256 / [blank] / UNDEF
* ALPN: server accepted h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=*.google.com
*  start date: Dec  2 08:35:57 2024 GMT
*  expire date: Feb 24 08:35:56 2025 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "script.google.com" matched cert's "*.google.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Google Trust Services; CN=WR2
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* using HTTP/2
* [HTTP/2] [1] OPENED stream for https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyZsn9eoSKlR86769TYdolbFVCO_CdoYCkGfaILOPrwI4WlpgeoAqyhRzW1NJjnUwpqhg/exec
* [HTTP/2] [1] [:method: GET]
* [HTTP/2] [1] [:scheme: https]
* [HTTP/2] [1] [:authority: script.google.com]
* [HTTP/2] [1] [:path: /macros/s/AKfycbyZsn9eoSKlR86769TYdolbFVCO_CdoYCkGfaILOPrwI4WlpgeoAqyhRzW1NJjnUwpqhg/exec]
* [HTTP/2] [1] [user-agent: curl/8.7.1]
* [HTTP/2] [1] [accept: */*]
> GET /macros/s/AKfycbyZsn9eoSKlR86769TYdolbFVCO_CdoYCkGfaILOPrwI4WlpgeoAqyhRzW1NJjnUwpqhg/exec HTTP/2
> Host: script.google.com
> User-Agent: curl/8.7.1
> Accept: */*
> 
* Request completely sent off
< HTTP/2 302 
< content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< access-control-allow-origin: *
< cache-control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< pragma: no-cache
< expires: Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
< date: Wed, 01 Jan 2025 16:13:55 GMT
< location: https://script.googleusercontent.com/macros/echo?user_content_key=a_JZACxnMzHvmJ7FIuFQsimlDsXw9p4WQu_6RlkJGJR7W3y3SyDItgWXCSPiyj65gJiGWLqFX1gMA7hv5-EZA6_FTCzus1tcm5_BxDlH2jW0nuo2oDemN9CCS2h10ox_1xSncGQajx_ryfhECjZEnCk9qPdalzknzNixLg84JbKg9egd38h6jKZQHu5zZcJAhjH_Q9hTDWNzuYdbT0ZYJhbUvovf4xr6UyjZxQYe343BHfuoTCx-fNz9Jw9Md8uu&lib=MpGjSvtrz_7jB8rA8XdQyflgPkSAan__R
< x-content-type-options: nosniff
< x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
< content-security-policy: frame-ancestors 'self'
< x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
< server: GSE
< alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000
< accept-ranges: none
< vary: Accept-Encoding
< 
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Moved Temporarily</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<!-- GSE Default Error -->
<H1>Moved Temporarily</H1>
The document has moved <A HREF="https://script.googleusercontent.com/macros/echo?user_content_key=a_JZACxnMzHvmJ7FIuFQsimlDsXw9p4WQu_6RlkJGJR7W3y3SyDItgWXCSPiyj65gJiGWLqFX1gMA7hv5-EZA6_FTCzus1tcm5_BxDlH2jW0nuo2oDemN9CCS2h10ox_1xSncGQajx_ryfhECjZEnCk9qPdalzknzNixLg84JbKg9egd38h6jKZQHu5zZcJAhjH_Q9hTDWNzuYdbT0ZYJhbUvovf4xr6UyjZxQYe343BHfuoTCx-fNz9Jw9Md8uu&amp;lib=MpGjSvtrz_7jB8rA8XdQyflgPkSAan__R">here</A>.
</BODY>
</HTML>
* Connection #0 to host script.google.com left intact


curl -L " script.google.com/macros/s/… " [{"Title":"テスト1","DueDate":"12/26/2024","DueTime":"08:59"}]% 


Now the prediction.
Looking at the output of the curl command, there is no problem on the Apps script side. If there is any problem, it is on the Botspress side (possibly not following redirect 302 correctly).

The URL works fine when accessed directly in a browser In an incognito window?

No, I can access that URL with regular Chrome.

No, not incognito mode, not a private window, it's a page with history.

If you want to access it from an external system such as Botpress, is it realistic to migrate to a custom GCP project? Currently, the GCP project for GAS is the default one provided by Google. (That is, you have not created a GCP project yourself.)

it is not needed to migrate to custom GCP for deploying as " Anyone even anonymous". Instead, contact your admin.

Run as the following user: myself
Users with access : All
appsscript.json
  "webapp": {     "executeAs": **"USER_DEPLOYING"**,     "access": **"ANYONE_ANONYMOUS"**   },

1.Only other explanation is you input the url incorrectly in Botpress. Did it end with /exec? 2. Maybe redeploy and input the newly created url into Botpress? Each time you deploy, you get a new url. 3. And when Botoress makes a request, can you check execution logs in Apps script-whether there is a log entry at that exact time? 4. Could you return html with HtmlService( instead of ContentService), redeploy with new url and see if that fixes 404?

After deploying, copy the URL and confirm that it ends with “/exec
“Version 1 doGet web app 2025/01/01 1:41:32 0.95 seconds done”
I could see the execution log in the Apps script.

`// JSONレスポンスを返すためのユーティリティ関数
function jsonResponse(data) {
const output = ContentService.createTextOutput();
output.setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
output.setContent(JSON.stringify(data));
// CORSヘッダーを手動で追加する
output.addHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');  // 任意のオリジンからのアクセスを許可
output.addHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS');  // 許可するHTTPメソッド
output.addHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');  // 許可するヘッダー
return output;
}`
Am I correct in changing the code to this?
